# What does it do - get transparency and drawing cache?

Tags: android

I'd like to ask you what does it do?

```
a = Color.alpha(pixel);
```

Is it geting transparency pixel?

And I'd like to ask what is it Dwaring Cache in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Color.alpha` get the value of the alpha channel. Android colors are `ARGB`, integer `32bits`, 8 bits per channel. It takes the value of A and it shift this value to the right of 24. Something like

```
   return pixel >>> 24;
```

Edit: alpha expresses the opacity of your color/pixel. Its range between `0`, fully transparent and `255` fully opaque

Comment: and this pixel tell me about transparency? or about what?

Comment: I edited my answer. it represents the opacity of the color. When its value is 0 you have a full transparent color